# Rspec/Spork: Disabling spork for one run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, spork

I have --drb set in my .rspec file, which means spork runs by default.

If, however, I want to run through tests once without spork, I either have to modify my .rspec, or stop spork.

Just wondering - is there some sort of flag such as --drb=false or --no-drb so that I can run tests once without drb?

Comment: I run test all the time without spork. Can you share your spec helper file?

Comment: Hi jspooner. To automatically run spork, just append "--drb" to your .rspec file. (Create the file in project root if it doesn't exist). It shouldn't require any changes to spec_helper, but just in case you can see mine here: https://gist.github.com/1260887

Comment: Sorry I was reading this on my phone and didn't get your full question.  I was thinking you get an error when running spec w/o spork.  I usually just kill spork to test w/o.

Comment: Hey PlankTon, did you find out a way to disable spork for one run? I'm looking to do this so I can drop into a test with Pry

Answer (score 1):

Just add `require 'spork'` at the beginning of your spec_helper.rb and it will initialize itself if there's no spork process running